# Ownership when each item in a vector needs all the other items in said vector

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm very new to Rust and I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle ownership (and lifetime?) in this case. I'm not new to programming and I'm actually re-implementing something that already works in JS (https://sheraff.github.io/boids/).

---

In this context, `Universe` is basically a "simulation" environment containing many `Entity`. On each `universe.tick()`, each `Entity` needs to know which other `Entity` it can "see". For that, `entity.update()` takes a list of `Entity` as an argument.

As a result, I have this piece of script that I can't seem to find a good ownership structure for:

```rust
for mut entity in self.entities {
    entity.update(&self.entities);
}
```

**How would you go about it?**

I could tell you what I have tried but it feels like I have tried everything I could think of, including reading the Rust book, and I've had all the possible error messages... Sorry.

---

PS: of course, in time, it's not the entire list of entities that would be passed in `entity.update` but a filtered list.

---

Below is a general simplification of the code structure:

```rust
pub struct Entity {
    pub point: Point,
    vision: Cone,
    angle: Angle
}
impl Entity {
    pub fn update(&mut self, entities: &Vec<Entity>) {
        // ...
    }
}

pub struct Universe {
    pub entities: Vec<Entity>
}
impl Universe {
    pub fn new() -> Universe {
        let mut entities: Vec<Entity> = vec![];
        for _ in 1..200 {
            let mut entity = Entity::new();
            entities.push(entity);
        }

        Universe {
            entities
        }
    }

    pub fn tick(&self) {
        for mut entity in self.entities {
            entity.update(&self.entities);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help to understand "rust ownership" https://youtu.be/TCUBSbJENO4

Comment: @nbari thank you, that was pretty good indeed. But it didn't go into borrows (though other of their videos seem to do) which seem crucial for the problem in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each entity needs to know about each entity, then it seems like it's not the entity that's responsible for the update. You should probably refactor from a method on the entity to a function that operates on all entities.

Iterating over the entities in a nested loop is a bit difficult. One solution would be to iterate over one copy of the array and allow the other loop to take a mutable reference.

```
pub fn update_entities(entities: &mut Vec<Entity>) {
    for a in entities.clone() {
        for mut entity in entities.iter_mut() {
            if entity.id == a.id { // If you can compare them, otherwise use indexed for loop and compare indices.
                continue;
            }
            // Do stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why you need to copy is because of the golden rule of Rust: *you can have either one mutable reference **or** any number of immutable references.* Nested for loops break this rule because you need one mutable reference and one immutable.

Comment: So there is never any nested loops in Rust? Except w/ cloning?

Comment: @Sheraff I don't know any good, clean way of doing it. Although, instead of copying, you could make the function completely pure (as defined in functional programming; no mutable state and no side-effects) and return a new entity array from an immutable input. That's probably what I would do, but it depends on what you're actually doing in your update.